# Image hotlinking providers?

Tags: image-hosting, hotlinking

I use a lot of images in my wordpress and due to hosting restrictions I need to host the images somewhere else and hotlink them in my blog posts. So I am looking for some reliable image host which provides free hotlinking service. 
The Google Picasa would be best, but I think they do not allow hotlinking.
PS. I'm not looking for hosts like tinypic or imgshack, I'm looking for some websites which provides powerful features to oranize images (eg. albums etc).

Comment: I don't understand the last bit about why not tinypic, et al. Do you want the host to let you organize **and** then provide some kind of wholesale gallery feature/widget that you can embed?

Comment: Photobucket no longer lets you direct link to an image alone and have just that image come up. So far you can still incorporate an image hosted there into your site or blog but if you want someone to click on a photobucket link direct to the image (the link ending in jpg) photobucket will serve up their own page displaying your photo instead of the photo alone. New policy they said. This is current as of March 2013.

Answer (score 2):

You will be hard pushed to find a site that does all that for free. However, [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) allows dead simple free image hosting with no discernible limits. There is a feature to group images into albums, but that is mainly for display on imgur itself and not your own organisation.

Your other alternative is a CDN solution like Amazon S3/Cloudfront. Unless your site is very popular (thousands of visitors a day) then it will be very cheap.

Comment: Imgur is a great image hosting site. There are limits for free usage, based on a maximum number of images or bandwidth, but I have been using it for just the sort of thing asked about, and have been very pleased. A paid account costs very little, and does remove quantity/ usage restrictions. Also, Imgur offers image editing with Aviary. It's a new-ish feature.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of people run their blog images off of [Flickr](http://flickr.com), including [slideshows](http://www.flickr.com/help/blogging/#2937). There are a couple of minor requirements, like the images linking back to Flickr, but if you want someone else to handle your media, especially if you're asking for free, you have to make some concessions. (In my experience, this isn't even always done and you'd probably have to be a major offender or reported to even get noticed.)

I've got a client with hundreds of galleries that we host there(Flickr Pro is $25/yr, which you're probably paying more for in hosting already). We required more control over the output(to use a custom Javascript gallery locally), so I used [phpFlickr](http://phpflickr.com/) to get the data into our templates. In this instance, we're able to move the backlink to a dedicated button rather than the image itself.